How to Configure Google Sign-In with AWS Cognito Using a Custom API (Node js)
I have successfully integrated Google Sign-In directly with AWS Cognito. The process works as expected: Google generates a code upon successful login, which can be verified by Cognito, resulting in the creation of an access token and a refresh token.
However, I am now trying to implement Google Sign-In through a custom API.
When using my custom API, Google generates a code that is not a UUID and cannot be directly verified through the Cognito API endpoint (https://cognito-domain/oauth2/token).
Here are the steps I followed:

Created a Google app and obtained the client ID and secret.
Registered the identity provider with the Cognito user pool, using the same client ID and secret.

How can I configure AWS Cognito to work with Google Sign-In when using a custom API? Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
